# Can't get cookie expiration to set

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cookies

Can't get cookie expiration to set

I'm using php to set a cookie on a wordpress site, but having a bit of difficulty as the content shows up every time the page is loaded instead of only showing up the first time a user visits the site (expires once a day).

Forgive me if this is obvious, I'm still learning ;)

Here's the function, I have this in my functions.php page:

```
function set_newuser_cookie() {
    if ( !is_admin() && !isset($_COOKIE['jtc_newvisitor'])) {
        setcookie('jtc_newvisitor', 1, time()+60*60*24, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false);
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'set_newuser_cookie');
```

Here is how I'm calling it:

```
<?php if (isset($_COOKIE['jtc_newvisitor'])) { ?>
    <div id="modal-notices">content</div>
<?php } else { } ?>
```

Here's my js, I'm using to have the content display when the page loads:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#modal-notices').modal('show');
});
```

I'd like to have the content load if it's the first time the user has visited the page within 24 hours, but as of now, it just loads every time.

If anyone can point me in the right direction here or explain what I'm doing wrong, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the cookie is being set? I'm also not clear on what your desired outcome is. Do you want the div with the ID `modal-notices` to only be output on the first visit, or on the second and subsequent?

Comment: Thanks @vvanasten I want the form to only show up the first time. How do I go about checking to see if the cookie has been set?

Comment: Checking cookies is different on every browser, [try this resource](http://kb.iu.edu/data/ajfi.html). It looks like you're displaying the `modal-notices` div only when the cookie is present (`if (isset($_COOKIE['jtc_newvisitor']))`). Try changing `isset` to `!isset`.

Comment: Thanks @vvanasten that was it! If you want to put that as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: thanks - @vvanasten has answered the question, though in a comment.

Comment: @EricBrockman I've added it as an answer. Let me know if you need more detail or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're checking if the cookie is set rather than if it's not set. Try this as your `if` statement:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['jtc_newvisitor']))
```